# Limitar tamanho do body, para ficar do tamanho do ecrã

Tags: html, css

Bom, o que pretendia era limitar o tamanho do body para que ficasse do tamanho do ecrã sem ter a necessidade de dar scroll. É porque estou a desenvolver um projeto em que fica muito espaço branco debaixo do rodapé e tenho que dar scroll, sem qualquer motivo, pois não tem lá conteudo.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: No fundo queres encontrar o problema para esse projeto e a razão de ter espaço em branco a mais, certo? nesse caso tens de partilhar informação sobre esse código para podermos ajudar. Para tirar o scroll podes fazer `body { height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` mas isso é muito genérico.

Comment: Resolveste o meu problema, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

> crie um css ou melhor dentro do css 
>   crie um .body{}
>   dentro dele defina margin!Margin são responsáveis pela delimitação da pagina
>   com isso todos elementos que fores a introduzir irão seguir e não vão sair dos ?>limites da margin.